# Issue with using row_count as ID column in mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm using this query to create a view:

```
create view daily_report as 

SELECT 
      row_count()
    , c.extension as Extension
    , RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
    , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
    FROM cdrdb.session a
    LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
            ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
    LEFT JOIN cdrdb.mxuser c
          ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
    GROUP BY c.extension;
```

And it's successful, but when I select the records from the view it has -1 as the value for all 6 records.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, exactly.

Comment: What is `row_count()` ??

Comment: We don't need all those complicated fields to help you. Try to reduce the problem to the minimum so we don't waste time trying to understand it. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was afraid they would be needed for context but I see what you mean. row_count is being used since this is mysql, instead of row_number for sqlserver

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0400__Information-Functions/ROWCOUNTreturnsthenumberofrowsupdatedinsertedordeletedbytheprecedingstatement.htm

Comment: I told you, either you create a store proc instead of a view or create a function to replace the user variables.

Comment: I did try the function but I don't have permissions on this read only database, so it fails

Comment: Well you can `create view` why cant you create a function? Talk to your DBA

Comment: We;re working on that, it's part of our phone vendor system unfortunately. Question: I have a table called ambition_test that has a PK ID column, could I join that table and use those values since they will be unique? I just don't know how I would join since nothing has a column I can equate it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For statements which return a result set (such as SELECT, SHOW, DESC or HELP), returns -1, even when the result set is empty. This is also true for administrative statements, such as OPTIMIZE.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there actually a way that I can easily select from this view so that I have an arbitrary ID column or auto-incrementing? I can't use variables because it's a variable and I've tried everything I've found thus far.

Comment: You can try to include the following in your select statement: `@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number`

Comment: I have tried that actually, but that's what I was referring to with variables. It returns error 1351

Comment: I see, it's a view. What if you try to subquery it: `(SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM [cdrdb.session] [c] WHERE [c].RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID < [cdrdb.session].RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID) AS row_number`

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax should be but I had to run it like this to get it to run, and it returns all '1' as values
```
    (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM cdrdb.session c WHERE c.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID < c.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID) AS row_number

```

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html

> SELECT: -1 if the statement returns a result set, 
>   or the number of rows “affected” if it does not.

For example, for

```
SELECT * FROM t1, ROW_COUNT() returns -1
```

Comment: I see, so it's actually returning -1 because it's a result set

Comment: Correct, only return ***affected*** rows in case of `UPDATE` or `DELETE`